# Python Selenium TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Recently, I wanted to create Instagram Bot in Python using Selenium. When I try to click the accept button, I get weird error. I'm a begginer, so it's probably something stupid. I would really appreciate any kind of help.

```
service = Service(CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)


class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    def login(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
        accept_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@id="mount_0_0_9k"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div['
                                                          '1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button[2]'))
        accept_button.click()


bot = InstaBot()
bot.login()
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwCEo.png)

Every time I got this error:
accept_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@id="mount_0_0_9k"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div['
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

`By.XPATH` isn't a function. `find_element(By.XPATH, "your-xpath")`.

Answer (score 0):

### *find_element()*

[`find_element()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element) finds an element given a [`By`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by) strategy and a locator and is defined as:

```
def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value: Optional[str] = None) -> WebElement:
    """Find an element given a By strategy and locator.

    :Usage:
        ::

            element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'foo')

    :rtype: WebElement
    """
```

---

### Solution

In your usecase instead of a `function` you need to pass a [***tuple***](https://towardsdatascience.com/10-examples-to-master-python-tuples-6c606ed42b96) as follows:

```
accept_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mount_0_0_9k"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button[2]'))
accept_button.click()
```